# Can I use https with Varnish Cache

Tags: https, varnish

Can I use varnish cache with https or will this have little to no performance gain? What are the pros and cons? I've set up my vcl for http only. I want to try this with https now.

I've read this but it's from 2011:
https://www.varnish-cache.org/docs/trunk/phk/ssl.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Varnish in itself does not support SSL and is very unlikely to do so in the overseeable future.

To use SSL and still be able to cache with varnish you have to terminate the SSL before the request is sent to varnish. This can be done efficiently by for instance HAProxy or Nginx.

To find out exactly how to configure this; a simple google search for `ssl termination haproxy/nginx` will yield more than enough results-

Comment: I'm using apache. So I guess I would need nginx alongside apache and varnish to make this work?

Comment: With huge traffic you might want to do that because it's a bit faster. But with with a bit more average traffic I would recommend you stick to Apache as the SSL termination proxy as well to not have to learn a new piece of software. This would mean your traffic goes HTTPS Apache -> HTTP Varnish -> HTTP Apache.

Answer (score 0):

You set the X-Forwarded-For headers in HAProxy. If there is already set an X-Forwarded-For header other reverse proxies will always just add their own to it, the left-most or first address is the source address. You don't have to think about that, anything that reads and uses X-Forwarded-For headers will sort that out automagically.

You also want to set the X-Forwarded-Proto so you can do all sorts of magic in Varnish, like redirecting traffic not using TLS without hitting your backend servers and separate the caches, as Varnish doesn't talk TLS, which can lead to some interesting results, like images not being served up because they are requested over HTTP when the page is served over HTTPS.

Side question, are you using HAProxy to actually load balance between multiple backends? If not, why not just terminate the TLS connection in Apache, send that to Varnish and then back to Apache again?